# How to catch all routes but ignore some URLs?

Tags: .net-core, routes

I'm starting to upgrade my old WebForms CMS which uses a catch all handler.
In .NET Core 2 I have created a route like:

```
routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "NodeHandler",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Node", action = "Index" );                                        
}
```

Which by default catch all. How do I get the route to ignore certain directories?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute-based routing.  In your controllers use the [NonAction] attribute so that no route will be created for an action.

The default route (template) is {controller}/{action}/{id} but you can have non-action methods using this technique.

[Controllers and Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.90).aspx)